# How to correctly add a VBA reference to a VBA add-in for Windows and macOS

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have a mutli-add-in VBA product as follows:

Add-In 1 = Common functions for add-ins 2 & 3

Add-In 2 = Feature set A

Add-In 3 = Feature set B

I can call functions in add-in one from the other two using Application.Run but I'd prefer to have IntelliSense help out so I added a reference to #1 and in #2 and #3. It works on Windows but when I install load all three components on a Mac, the reference UI reports that "Add-In 1.ppam" is MISSING and reports that it can't be found in /Users/[username]Library/Containers/ even if "Add-In1" is in the list and unchecked.

How can I use a VBA add-in in this way on both Windows and macOS for Microsoft 365 apps?

Comment: I've not done that on either platform. Add to your post the reference you use on Windows and maybe that will help us help you to find a Mac equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Rich. The reference is my compiled VBA add-in, not a Microsoft library.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right path? I put my add-ins in /Users/<Home>/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/ and then depending on the Office application, either the Add-Ins or Startup subfolder.

Comment: I put my add-ins there too but the VBE is reporting that the referenced add-in is unavailable and it seems to be looking in that path by default. It feels like there's something wrong with the way paths are used when transferring a multi-add-in product from PC to Mac.

Comment: I finally had to give up on adding references to my own complied ppam components within other ppam components and instead make the inter-add-in procedure calls the hard way using `Application.Run`, without the benefit of IntelliSense.